# I am using python 3.2 and pip 6.0.6, when I run scrapy startproject tutorial I get the following error

Tags: python, scrapy

When I run the command scrapy startproject tutorial, i get lots of lines of errors and at the end AttributeError:'NoneType'object has no attribute 'startswith'. In the previous lines it is pointing to various lines in various files

```
c:\Python27>scrapy startproject tutorial
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Scrapy==0.24.4', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 519, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group,name)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2630, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2310, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py",line 2316, in resolve
    module=__import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    __version__=pkgutil.get_data(__package__, 'VERSION').decode('ascii').strip()
  File "C:\Python32\lin\pkgutil.py", line 565, in get_data
    loader=get_loader(package)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\pkgutil.py", line 453, in get_loader
    return find_loader(fullname)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\pkgutil.py", line 463, in find_loader
    for importer in iter_importers(fullname):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\pkgutil.py", line 413, in iter_importers
    if fullname.startswith('.'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType'object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: post your code, how can we see the lines??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy [does not support Python 3](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/faq.html#faq-python-versions):

> What Python versions does Scrapy support? Scrapy is supported under
>   Python 2.7 only. Python 2.6 support was dropped starting at Scrapy
>   0.20.
>
> Does Scrapy work with Python 3? No, but there are plans to support
>   Python 3.3+. At the moment, Scrapy works with Python 2.7.

You need to use Python 2.7.

Comment: Update your question and add the lines of errors that you see.